# dig returns status of refused?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I am dealing with a barrel of weasels on this one. Ad agency registered the domain in mid-August with Network Solutions. 72 hours ago I updated the DNS to point to a host provided by an associate of the client whose credentials are dubious.

The DNS servers are at NETSONIC.NET (NS1 and NS2) and respond to ping no problem.

I can FTP to the server using its IP but the name is no go. The name is also no go for tracert and ping:

```
tracert voodoobbqfranchise.com
Unable to resolve target system name voodoobbqfranchise.com.

ping voodoobbqfranchise.com
ping: unknown host voodoobbqfranchise.com


// Note that using dig to query other domains 
// hosted on that server returns just fine

dig voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns1.netsonic.net

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns1.netsonic.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 38967
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;voodoobbqfranchise.com.                IN      A

;; Query time: 73 msec
;; SERVER: 216.235.75.2#53(216.235.75.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 13 13:43:08 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Can anyone give an opinion as to what is up here?  Is the host account misconfigured?

TIA

JG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine now.... likely wasn't configured at the time you tested.

**$ dig ns voodoobbqfranchise.com @a.gtld-servers.net**

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> ns voodoobbqfranchise.com @a.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21226
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;voodoobbqfranchise.com.        IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns1.netsonic.net.
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns2.netsonic.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.netsonic.net.   172800  IN  A   216.235.75.2
ns2.netsonic.net.   172800  IN  A   66.180.161.2

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 13 15:24:47 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120

**$ dig voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns1.netsonic.net**

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns1.netsonic.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33428
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;voodoobbqfranchise.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 900 IN  A   66.180.170.5

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 1209600 IN  NS  ns1.netsonic.net.
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 1209600 IN  NS  ns2.netsonic.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.netsonic.net.   86400   IN  A   216.235.75.2
ns2.netsonic.net.   86400   IN  A   66.180.161.2

;; Query time: 108 msec
;; SERVER: 216.235.75.2#53(216.235.75.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 13 15:22:40 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 136

**$ dig voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns2.netsonic.net**

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns2.netsonic.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11817
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;voodoobbqfranchise.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 900 IN  A   66.180.170.5

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 1209600 IN  NS  ns1.netsonic.net.
voodoobbqfranchise.com. 1209600 IN  NS  ns2.netsonic.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.netsonic.net.   86400   IN  A   216.235.75.2
ns2.netsonic.net.   86400   IN  A   66.180.161.2

;; Query time: 107 msec
;; SERVER: 66.180.161.2#53(66.180.161.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 13 15:22:44 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 136

Comment: Thanks, yes.  We managed to convince person providing hosting to examine the settings at the host and his edits corrected it.  Thank you for looking